# ValueError when importing a praw script

Tags: python, import, python-3.5, praw, valueerror

can someone help me?

Let me explain myself better.
I have this folder structure:

```
praw-test
    jobs
        __init__.py
        redisJob.py
    main.py
```

and if I run directly `python jobs\redisJob.py` it works just fine.

But, if I try to import the file `redisJob.py` in `main.py` it gives me this error:

```
File ".\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jobs.redisJob import DailyJob
  File "D:\git\praw-test\jobs\redisJob.py", line 5, in <module>
    import praw
  File "D:\git\praw-test\env\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .reddit import Reddit  # NOQA
  File "D:\git\praw-test\env\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 5, in <module>
    from update_checker import update_check
  File "D:\git\praw-test\env\lib\site-packages\update_checker.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
  File "D:\git\praw-test\env\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    major, minor, patch = urllib3_version
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Just to make sure, the import command is

```
from jobs.redisJob import DailyJob
```

Did I do something wrong?

**Update**
I found a workaround.
I just need to import `urllib3` in my `main.py` then assigning the correct version.

```
import urllib3
urllib3.__version__ = '1.21.1'
from jobs.redisJob import DailyJob
```

These three lines have to be on top of my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're importing under a different environment.  Different launch techniques can spawn different processes and shells; this could lead to the environment variable having a value other than expected.

I don't know enough SDE details to give you a definitive solution, but I can certainly recommend a simple debugging line.  Just before the problem line, insert

```
print urllib3_version
```

See what you get for the value in each launch method.  I expect that there's some implementation detail, such as the values being concatenated somehow, or having some missing.

You can work around this with a check:

```
if len(urllib3_version) == 3:
    major, minor, patch = urllib3_version
else:
    # This will depend on what you see in the single value
```

You may need to split a string, supply defaults for missing values, or some other adaptation.

Comment: `python main.py` prints `dev` and `python jobs\redisJob.py` prints `1.21.1`. How can I fix that without having to edit manually the module?

Comment: Ok, I found a workaround, I edited my post. Thank to you obviously, I'd never think to edit a module like urllib3!